# Android, Adding FaceBook Login with Existing Login (SDK 4.0.1)?

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have an app, which already uses email and a database to log users in and out. I would like to incorporate a Facebook login, but am not sure how to track users.

I follow the code from Facebook [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3), and it works fine to log in using Facebook, but I am unsure how to track users.

With the email login, it is as simple as comparing the email and password with what is stored in the database, but what information is available to store when they use FB to log on? People can change their names, email, etc, and even access tokens change every 6 months.

If I store anything that might potentially change, then there will be a mismatch with the database, and then they won't be able to log on anymore.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm searching for this too. I have a feeling that using the uid of the facebook user would work so long as the api is secure because it will only be generated on a mobile client. On web, I'm not sure I think it would be a more complex task. But as of now my plan is just to store facebook uid since no one can mimic the auth api is secure.

Comment: If you found the solution though please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

-Hello please correct me if i am wrong 
-As per facebook documentation

-

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  ProfileTracker profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(
                Profile oldProfile,
                Profile currentProfile) {
            // App code
        }
    };
```

-Can be used with it.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at that in the same link in my question, but they don't say a whole lot about it. If that is the case, I can search for their old token in the DB and then replace it with the new one, but I'm not entirely certain how to use it. Thanks though, I might have to play around with this one. 60 days it a long time to wait for a token to change, to test if it is all working properly.

Comment: I'm not sure about tracking access tokens with the [profileTracker](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/ProfileTracker/), but the [accessTokenTracker](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AccessTokenTracker/) likely will do the trick. 

With the profile tracker, I'm not sure if it monitors if a new user logs on, or if the token changes.